# how to open google oauth2 url in iframe

Tags: iframe, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a url that starts with https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth...
I deleted the following parameters for security purposes.
when i try to open this url in iframe.

I am getting this error in console

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

and screenshot

[image]

my code

```
<iframe src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth..." width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to show google oauth2 site in app with iframe or other way?